# Convert a column of dataframe to numpy array or tensor based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

Consider a dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'r': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'c': [0, 2, 1, 2], 'v': [2, 4, 3, 5],})
```

I want to extract a numpy array or tensor considering 'r' and 'c' as row and column index of the matrix. so the corresponding matrix will be like:

```
arr = array([[0, 0, 0],
   [2, 0, 4],
   [0, 3, 5]])
```

So is there a decent way to do that or I have to loop through each df row? what about extracting dataframe df from a matrix like arr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a `numpy` array from the dataframe considering `r` and `c` as the `row` and `column` index:

```
r, c, v = df.T.values
arr = np.zeros((r.max() + 1, c.max() + 1))
arr[r, c] = v
```

---

```
>>> arr

array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 4.],
       [0., 3., 5.]])
```

To recreate the dataframe from the `numpy` array like above you can use **[`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)** to get the indices of the elements that are non-zero:

```
r, c = np.nonzero(arr)
df = pd.DataFrame({'r': r, 'c': c, 'v': arr[r, c]})
```

---

```
>>> df

   r  c    v
0  1  0  2.0
1  1  2  4.0
2  2  1  3.0
3  2  2  5.0
```